# Looking for TINI SDK

Tags: software, java, 1-wire

I've to do some work on TINIS400 & TINIM400 evaluation kit From Dallas Semiconductor. These boards are now obsolete and the TINI SDK is therfore no longer available on the Dallas Semiconductor website.

Any idea where I might be able to download the TINI SDK?

Thanks..

Comment: Did you ask their local FAE?

Comment: Yes. No response yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a mirror of the old SDKs on ...

Grab it while it's still there!  (I can confirm the download, just pulled it down myself)

Kind regards,
Andi

PS: I forgot how to do the firmware uploads, it was a normal RS232 but needed DTR/DSR (I think) as well to put the device in flash mode.  Ah, coming back to me now, just check the docs/ directory.  Only problem you (and I) may face is that the upgrade needs a minimum prior version on the device, meaning you may have to download another earlier version to bridge a very old firmware to the latest 17

Comment: Someone pointed out that this might be illegal. I doubt it would be prosecuted if it is as this is a discontinued product and these were openly available files. I would welcome input from another whom has better legal knowledge then myself. However we do not promote pirating an engineers good work I doubt this is a case of that.

Comment: OK, link removed; I'll just use my archived version.  Apologies, I didn't read the license, redistribution is not granted, and since it's not on the dalsemi FTP server, I presume they don't want engineers to use the kit any more.

Comment: and issues solved